# exercise 2.2.14 from Classical Fourier Analysis about an inequality

Tags: inequality, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $-\infty<\alpha<\frac{n}{2}<\beta<+\infty$. Prove the validity of the following inequality:
$\|g\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}\leq C\||x|^{\alpha}g(x)\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^{\frac{\beta-n/2}{\beta-\alpha}}\||x|^{\beta}g(x)\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^{\frac{n/2-\alpha}{\beta-\alpha}}$
for some constant $C=C(n,\alpha,\beta)$ independent of $g$

The author gives us a hint: First prove $\|g\|_{L^{1}}\leq C\||x|^{\alpha}g(x)\|_{L^{2}}+\||x|^{\beta}g(x)\|_{L^{2}}$ and then replace $g(x)$ by $g(\lambda x)$ for some suitable $\lambda>0$

According to the author's hint, I have proven the ultimate estimate by scaling and balance method, but how to prove **the inequality in the hint**?

Comment: I would start with $\|g\|_{L^1}=\int_{|x|\leq 1}|g(x)|\,dx+\int_{|x|>1}|g(x)|$. In the two regions, multiply and divide by appropriate powers of $|x|$ and then use Cauchy-Schwarz (that's why you have the two borderline conditions $\alpha<\frac{n}{2}<\beta$; small powers work close to the origin, and while large powers work away from the origin, and $n/2$ is the critical case which fails everywhere). Here, "work" means "has finite integral".

Comment: thank you 
@peek-a-boo

Comment: I will try it! Best wishes!!

Comment: Thank you very much, I have done it thanks to your idea!!!